# Why do I keep overwriting the content I am pointing to in my linked list?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

For a client-server model I want to 'save' all the logged in users in a linked list together with their filedescriptors. I tried to do the following:

When the user types in the command to login it returns the username he or she picked.
Then afterwards it adds this username to a linked list.

```
      char* username = login(clientSocket, message);
      addUser(username, clientSocket);
```

Adding the username and socket to the linked list happens as follows:

```
typedef struct UserSocketNode {
    int userSocket;
    char* username;
    struct UserSocketNode* next;
}UserSocketNode;

UserSocketNode *head = NULL;

void addUser(char* username, int userSocket) {
    UserSocketNode *newNode = (UserSocketNode*) malloc(sizeof(UserSocketNode));
    newNode->username = (char*)malloc(strlen(username) + 1);

    newNode->userSocket = userSocket;
    strcpy(newNode->username, username);

    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;
}
```

Whenever I print the contents of my linked list every node has the same username and I can't figure out why. It makes sense to me that by allocating memory for the node I don't allocate memory for the char array where I save the username and sub-sequentially every node would point to the same username. I thought I fixed this by explicitly allocating memory for the username and copy the contents of the char array to the newNode->username, but this doesn't work.

Could anyone give me some pointers on where I am wrong.

Comment: Start with checking what `username` is that `login` returns.

Comment: What happens if you print the contents of `newNode->username` once you `strcpy`? What is printed?

Comment: Exactly what I need it to be. If I want to login with 'user1' it returns "user1" at least the pointer to that char array. This answer is for Paul Ogilvie's question.

Comment: @Cuijpie try printing the pointer location of username when you print your list. See if the pointers are different. `printf(“%p”,username)` - edit - don’t copy paste that. I’m on mobile and quotes are converted to special utf quotes.

Comment: Can't reproduce - see https://ideone.com/NrW7ZT The problem is most likely in some code you didn't post.... btw: Post the code used for printing the list

Comment: @Kyle Thanks for reminding me to print the pointers! I realized that the problem was not in my code, but that I made an error in my makefile that made it not compile. Totally my bad!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, nothing wrong with your approach. You have a bug elsewhere.

Your linked list node contains two data elements and a next pointer,

```
typedef struct UserSocketNode {
    int userSocket;
    char* username;
    struct UserSocketNode* next;
} UserSocketNode;
```

You have a list of `UserSocketNode`, call it something that indicates what it is. I would keep a head & tail, and add at tail, but that is me.

```
UserSocketNode* UserSocketList = NULL;
```

I would pass the list (sort of like a this/self), but hey...
Anyway, why not use strdup?

```
void UserSocketListadd(char* username, int userSocket)
{
    //need a new node
    UserSocketNode* node = (UserSocketNode*) malloc(sizeof(UserSocketNode));
    if( !node ) return; //error...
    //initialize
    node->userSocket = userSocket;
    node->username = strdup(username);

    //add to front of list
    node->next = UserSocketList;
    UserSocketList = node;
}
```